# Basis for Product Topology w/o using subspaces

Tags: general-topology

The usual way I found that

$\mathcal{B}:=\{\prod_{i\in I}U_i| U_i\in \tau_i \textit{ and } U_i=X_i \textit{ for all but finite } i\}$

is a Basis for the Product topology is to show that it is the intersection of subspaces based on projections. I wonder If one can prove this using the usual characterization of topological basis:

(1) $X=\bigcup_{B\in \mathcal{B}}B$

(2) $B_1,B_2\in \mathcal{B}, p\in B_1\cap B_2\Rightarrow \exists B_3:p\in B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$

So in this case we would have to show that $x\in \prod X_i\Rightarrow x\in\bigcup_{B\in \mathcal{B}}B$ and the other direction. I am somehow lost on the indices. Can this be showed w/o Subspaces? Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product topology is generally **defined** to be the topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$, so I assume that what you’re asking is whether it can be proved directly that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for **some** topology.

$X_i\in\tau_i$ for each $i\in I$, so $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_i\in\mathscr{B}$. Clearly $B\subseteq X$ for each $B\in\mathscr{B}$, so $X=\bigcup\mathscr{B}$. This proves (1).

Now suppose that $p\in B_1\cap B_2$, where $B_1,B_2\in\mathscr{B}$. Let $B_1=\prod_{i\in I}U_i$ and $B_2=\prod_{i\in I}V_i$, where $U_i,V_i\in\tau_i$ for each $i\in I$, and there are finite sets $F_1,F_2\subseteq I$ such that $U_i=X_i$ if $i\in I\setminus F_1$, and $V_i=X_i$ if $i\in I\setminus F_2$. Let $W_i=U_i\cap V_i\in\tau_i$ for each $i\in I$, and let $B=\prod_{i\in I}W_i$. Clearly $B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$, and $p_i\in U_i\cap V_i=W_i$ for each $i\in I$, so $p\in B$. Finally, $F_1\cup F_2$ is finite, and $W_i=U_i\cap V_i=X_i\cap X_i=X_i$ for each $i\in I\setminus(F_1\cup F_2)$, so $B\in\mathscr{B}$. This proves (2).

Comment: Thank you Professor!

Comment: @Averroes2: You’re welcome!